# Create Buttons On-Screen in regular intervals

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, kotlin, timer

I have a function that creates buttons dynamically at random positions on screen. I'm trying to call this function at regular intervals until the max amount of buttons allowed on screen is reached. I also want to use similar logic to control the buttons visibility after a few seconds.

I've tried doing this with a Timer and TimerTask but the app always crashes, is there something I'm doing wrong should I use Runnables or Threads instead?

```
var numOfBtns: Int = 0
var randX = 0
var randY = 0
val numberOfButtonsToCreate = 3

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_buttons)

    val displaymetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displaymetrics)
    val width = displaymetrics.widthPixels // 1080
    val height = displaymetrics.heightPixels // 1794

    val timer: Timer = Timer()
    var timerTask = timerTask {
        run(){

                randX = Random.nextInt(30, width - 250)
                randY = Random.nextInt(90, height - 144)
                CreateButtons(randX, randY)

        }
    }

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 3000)

}
```

Crash Info:

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
Process: com.example.clickinggameproject, PID: 10626
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8798)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1606)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25390)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5062)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5036)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.addContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:713)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.addContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:185)
    at com.example.clickinggameproject.testButtonsActivity.CreateButtons(testButtonsActivity.kt:63)
    at com.example.clickinggameproject.testButtonsActivity$CreateButtonTimer$$inlined$timerTask$1.run(Timer.kt:150)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
```

Added this to the CreateButtons function which fixed the problem but now I can't figure out why the other buttons dont populate on screen after first run??

```
 fun CreateButtons(posx: Int, posy: Int){
    this.runOnUiThread() {
 }
```

Comment: Post the crash info!

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks actually this helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already discovered that you can only work with your views on the main thread. As for why it only runs once: You called `timer.schedule` without specifying an interval, so it only runs one time. If you want it to run repeatedly, you have to specify the third parameter of the function.

Also, if you have a repeating timer, you have to call `cancel()` on it in `onDestroy()`, or it will keep running after the Activity is closed. So store your timer in a property so you can access it in `onDestroy()` to cancel it, like this:

```
private val timer = Timer()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //...

    val timerTask = timerTask {
        run(){
            val randX = Random.nextInt(30, width - 250)
            val randY = Random.nextInt(90, height - 144)
            CreateButtons(randX, randY)

        }
    }

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 3000)

}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    timer.cancel()
}
```

I also want to mention, since your function isn't doing anything blocking, it would be simpler to do this with a coroutine. Then you don't have to worry about canceling it or making sure you aren't on some background thread. You could remove `runOnUiThread` from your `CreateButtons` function and do this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //...

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        while(true){
            delay(3000)
            val randX = Random.nextInt(30, width - 250)
            val randY = Random.nextInt(90, height - 144)
            CreateButtons(randX, randY)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if I wanted to add the ability to turn buttons invisible after x seconds could I also do this as a coroutine in the create buttons function before the onclicklistener?

Comment: Assuming you want each created button to have its own timer, you could launch another coroutine inside the CreateButtons function that calls `delay()` and then changes the visibility.